# Выборка данных из MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, выборка, reactjs

Привет!

Ответьте пожалуйста как можно достать данные из mongo через javascript в отдельном модуле. Может я что то не так понимаю, но к примеру (учу реакт) - есть компонент, который выводит например список городов, как организовать вывод этих городов в компоненте. Помогите, я не понимаю что уже делать (

Comment: Вроде официальные доки на монгу неплохие, не смотрели ещё?

Comment: Я очень плохо знаю английский, но здесь вопрос даже глобальней, скорее всего что то упускаю, раньше работал только с вордпресс который берет всю работу с базой на себя, и такой момент как просто организовать вывод данных из бд (любой вообще) посредством javascript для меня остается загадкой

Comment: Вы опишите подробнее, где у вас javascript работает. Если на сервере это одно, если в браузере это другое. Если ещё где-то - третье.

Comment: я использую nodejs, express для бек-энда, react для фронта.

Comment: Тогда два варианта - либо в express при рендере на сервере вставлять данные, полученные из монги, либо отдельно запросом с клиента получать.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ